A book to review abstract algebra?
Lately I'm reading some books of commutative algebra, and I could understand what the writer says but do not know the big picture, and sometimes get stuck while reading. Also, I find some concepts in abstract algebra which is not mentioned in "Algebra" by Artin, so I wanna purchase one book which could help me review the topics in abstract algebra, well if it could bring me to advanced topic, that would be great!
I've heard some graduate textbooks like serge lang, dummit, hungerford and so on,but they have different characteristics, just like lang's book they say is just like a big dictionary, dummit covers too many, and is so long, hungerford I don't know whether it's suitable to me, and others like AMA by Rotman, I don't know which could satisfy me if I just wanna review abstract algebra and learn commutative algebra first

Artin is about the most sophisticated undergraduate text. You need more graduate material, presumably. Try Lang, Dummit & Foote, or maybe Aluffi. You haven't provided any specifics here.

@Ted Shirfrin Well, that's my fault, I have heard several books of graduate like serge lang, dummit, hungerford, jackson, lang's book they say is a big dictionary, dummit's is so long, aluffi they say is full of catagory, so I don't know how to choose, I just wanna review the abstract algebra and learn commutative algebra first

What specifically are you not finding covered in Artin? Be specific.

Two books I can vouch for are Abstract Algebra by Pinter and Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications by Thomas Judson. The former is what I would consider to be the "definitive" self-study book for the subject. Judson's book is free and open-source. While I have not read it myself, some friends of mine have praised it.
